# How can I get Bottle to restart on file change?

Tags: python, cherrypy, bottle

I'm really enjoying [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/) so far, but the fact that I have to CTRL+C out of the server and restart it every time I make a code change is a big hit on my productivity. I've thought about using [Watchdog](http://packages.python.org/watchdog/) to keep track of files changing then restarting the server, but how can I do that when the `bottle.run` function is blocking.

Running the server from an external script that watches for file changes seems like a **lot** of work to set up. I'd think this was a universal issue for Bottle, CherryPy and etcetera developers.

Thanks for your solutions to the issue!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Check out from the tutorial a section entitled ["Auto Reloading"](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#auto-reloading)

> During development, you have to restart the server a lot to test your
>   recent changes. The auto reloader can do this for you. Every time you
>   edit a module file, the reloader restarts the server process and loads
>   the newest version of your code.

This gives the following example:

```
from bottle import run
run(reloader=True)
```

Comment: Oh, cool! Are there any situations in which this will fail to reload a module? I assume it watches all imported modules

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough experience to be able to say one way or the other.

Comment: It watches all imported modules and then completely restarts the server process. There is currently no way to add additional files to the watch-list (e.g. templates) but templates are not cached in debug mode anyway.

Comment: I wish I could tell it to restart any time I change my configuration files though

Comment: To defnulls point, you can enable debug by:  
`from bottle import debug`
...
`debug(True)`

Answer (score 4):

With

```
run(reloader=True)
```

there are situations where it does not reload like when the import is inside a def. To force a reload I used

```
subprocess.call(['touch', 'mainpgm.py'])
```

and it reloads fine in linux.

Answer (score 3):

Use `reloader=True` in `run()`.  Keep in mind that in windows this must be under `if __name__ == "__main__":` due to the way the `multiprocessing` module works.

```
from bottle import run

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(reloader=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

These scripts should do what you are looking for.

**AUTOLOAD.PY**

```
import os
def cherche(dir):
    FichList = [ f for f in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir,f)) ]
    return FichList

def read_file(file):
    f = open(file,"r")
    R=f.read()
    f.close()
    return R

def load_html(dir="pages"):
    FL = cherche(dir)
    R={}
    for f in FL:
        if f.split('.')[1]=="html":
            BUFF = read_file(dir+"/"+f)
            R[f.split('.')[0]] = BUFF
    return R
```

**MAIN.PY**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Version 1.0 00:37


import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
import datetime
import ast
from bottle import route, run, template, get, post, request, response, static_file, redirect

#AUTOLOAD by LAGVIDILO
import autoload
pages = autoload.load_html()




BUFF = ""
for key,i in pages.iteritems():
    BUFF=BUFF+"@get('/"+key+"')\n"
    BUFF=BUFF+"def "+key+"():\n"
    BUFF=BUFF+" return "+pages[key]+"\n"

print "=====\n",BUFF,"\n====="
exec(BUFF)


run(host='localhost', port=8000, reloader=True)
```